# How to reference an element using @ViewChild/@ContentChild when transcluded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am following [this cookbook](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) on how to create components dynamically at run time. It all works splendidly, as long as the element I am trying to reference using `@ViewChild` is not [transcluded (aka Content Projection in Angular 2)](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content) in another element.

Let me elaborate. I have this code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'module-landing',
    templateUrl: './module-landing.template.html',
    entryComponents: [TravelHeaderContentComponent]
 })
 export class ModuleLandingComponent implements AfterViewInit {
     @ViewChild(ContentHostDirective) contentHost: ContentHostDirective;

     ngAfterViewInit() {
         console.log(this.contentHost);
     }
 }
```

My `module-landing.template.html` looks like this:

```
<some-other-component></some-other-component>
<ng-template content-host></ng-template>
```

So far, so good. The `console.log()` outputs the object as expected.

However, I need to transclude the `content-host` element within the `some-other-component`, like this:

```
<some-other-component>
    <ng-template content-host></ng-template>
</some-other-component>
```

This falls over. The `@ViewChild()` reference is now `undefined`. Changing `@ViewChild()` to `@ContentChild()` has no effect.

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it https://plnkr.co/edit/LK6AfOgSz586DalhSU9U?p=preview Can you improve this plunker to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your response @yurzui. Your plnkr is not substantially different to my code, yet I get `undefined` whereas you get `[Object object]`. I guess it's a case a picking through and seeing where the difference lies.

Comment: My `some-other-component` is actually in a different module. Perhaps that's messing with Angular's head?

Comment: Try your code in plunker. I want to see it

Comment: I'm just on my way home so I will do that in the morning...

Comment: Content projection means you have to use @ ContentChild instead of @ ViewChild and involved ng-content - you have plural versions too... Had to look up transclusion.. So referenced it in your post for others who joined the Angular party on Angular 2+

Comment: ie when you have transclusion use @ContentChild/@ContentChildren

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYvIjd8rCVQ - Ionic example.. uses Angular 2+ under covers. But discusses this stuff quite nicely