# Binding a boolean value using *ngIf

Tags: angular

*component.ts*:

```
public myFlag: boolean = false;
changeFlag(){
  this.myFlag = true;
}
```

*component.html*:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="newPOST">{{newPOST}}</ng-template>
```

I expect to see the **true** when I press the button that calls `changeFlag()` but in my console is always like this:

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
```

This doesn't become true. How can I bind this boolean every time I press the button to change it?

Comment: where are you calling `changeFlag`??

Comment: I want to load specific html when the user use toggle (true,false) but I figured that the boolean never change, it is always false.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I'm calling `changeFlag` in the same component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out according to your example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj6ynr)

---

Here is the same code, posted here in case of something happens again to the StackBlitz.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myFlag = false;
}
```

```html
<button (click)="myFlag = !myFlag">Toggle</button>
<div *ngIf="myFlag" style="color:green">Hey I'm true</div>
<div *ngIf="!myFlag" style="color:red">Hey I'm false</div>
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
```

Comment: Consider moving the relevant parts of the stackblitz into your answer. Link only answers tend not to attract many upvotes and also can go stale if the link disappears.

Comment: Please, correct the example in the link or, even better, put the code in your answer.

Comment: @informaticienzero Someone changed my example, Based on the question I believe the main idea is to toggle between two divs using boolean. I updated the example thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`*ngIf` does not work with `<ng-template>` as it is [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directives) . You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311574/6555572)

As a work around you can use `*ngIf else` to achieve it

```
<div *ngIf="!myFlag;else myFlagTrue;">
</div>
<ng-template #myFlagTrue>{{myFlag}}</ng-template>
```

Here is the working **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exxrm9?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: This is good example, but it doesn't work as I want, my problem is that I press submit button `changeFlag(flag)` in `car.component` for example, and I send the flag (which is true) with it to the other function in the `bus.component` for example and inside the bus.component I write `this.myFlag = flag` everything is fine in my console, but still false in my html page.

Answer (score 2):

`*ngIf` doesn't wotk with `<ng-template>`.

Use `<ng-container>` for `*ngIf`-checking instead of `div`. If you are using `div` so you will have empty `div` in your template, if `myFlag` is false.

For example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myFlag; else myFlagFalse;">
  {{newPOST}}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #myFlagFalse>
  // something, if myFlag is false
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `myFlag` variable alone

```
<ng-template *ngIf="myFlag">{{newPOST}}</ng-template>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. this is my console: <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "function (isNew) {\r\n        va"
}-->

Comment: There is no changes, no results, just in my console I got:
`<!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "function (isNew) {\r\n va" }--> –`

Comment: @Aravind check my answer,use that stackblitz link and use `<ng-template *ngIf="myFlag">{{newPOST}}</ng-template>` there