# Angular binding ng-if

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not able to binding properly, it should toggle on click. ng-reflect-ng-if becomes true and it remains true, again on click it should be false, I tried (clickoutside) also but no luck. Followed this question also from stackoverflow
[Binding a boolean value using *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006599/binding-a-boolean-value-using-ngif)

```
<!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
```

---

TS code

```
 showAdditionalGraceInfo: boolean = false;
showAdditionalGraceInfo: boolean = false;

       toggleAdditionalGraceInfo() {

        this.showAdditionalGraceInfo = !this.showAdditionalGraceInfo;
        if(this.showAdditionalGraceInfo === true){
          this.showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper = true;
       } else{
         this.showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper = false
       }
      }
```

HTML code

```
 <span (click)="toggleAdditionalGraceInfo()">
                        <span *ngIf="showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper">
                            {{graceDaysAdditionalInfo}}
                        </span>
                    </span>
```

Comment: Your two fields are both `showAdditionalGraceInfo` did you intend one to be `showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Look at the first two lines of your ts code

Comment: `toggleAdditionalGraceInfo() {

        this.showAdditionalGraceInfo = !this.showAdditionalGraceInfo;}` Earlier it was like, but on click it was not getting true so I added more conditions now it becomes true but once its true it remains true

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Code TS

```
toggleAdditionalGraceInfo() {
    if(!this.showAdditionalGraceInfo){
      this.showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper = true;
   } else{
     this.showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper = false
   }
}
```

Code HTML

```
<span (click)="toggleAdditionalGraceInfo()">
   <ng-container *ngIf="showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper">
     <span>{{graceDaysAdditionalInfo}}</span>
   </ng-container>
</span>
```

Comment: It again becomes true but not false

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need two  variables for what you are trying to do. This is how you can do it if you must use both those variables.

```html
<span id="test" (click)="showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper = showAdditonalGraceInfo = 
  !showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper">
        <span *ngIf="showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper">
          {{graceDaysAdditionalInfo}}
      </span>
</span>
```

```
  showAdditionalGraceInfoWrapper:boolean = true;
  showAdditonalGraceInfo:boolean = true;
  graceDaysAdditionalInfo: string = "test"
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vlfmur

Comment: It again becomes true but not false

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I updated the answer to show the current value of all variables. You can see it toggles between true and false.